# Prove that a give sequence of function is a base of $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider $(\phi_k)_{k \geq0} \in \mathcal C^{\infty}([0,1])$ with $\phi_k \not\equiv 0 $ such that 
$$\int_0^1 \phi_k(s) ds = 0, \quad \forall k\geq 1$$ and $$\sup_{ t \in [0,1]} \left | \frac{d}{dt} \phi_k(t)\right| \leq R \ k, \quad \forall k\geq 0 $$

with $R>0$. Does a such family exist ? Does a such family constitute a orthonormal base for for $L^2([0,1])$ ?

Obviously it exist! We can answer those questions very fast giving an straightforward example consisting the furrier basis where $\phi_k(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{2 k \pi i  t}, \quad \forall t \in [0,1]$\

But how to answer the question without giving an example?

Comment: $\phi_k = 0$ for all $k$ will satisfy the equations.

Comment: thank you for detecting my typo

Comment: Still an issue...

Comment: $\phi_k =0$ STILL works.

Comment: Did you mean $=\delta_{kl}$?

Comment: If you are simply asked whether something exists, it is sufficient to present an example. However, depending on your audience you may have to show that your example is indeed a basis. If you are asked to show that any set of functions (except 0) which meets those criteria is a basis, you have some work to do.

Comment: Thank you Betty Mock! But I'm still interested in knowing what this work must be ...

Comment: Actually, your example of the Fourier basis violates your second requirement. The way the question is phrased right now, such a basis cannot exist since $\int_0^1 \! u \, dx = 0$ is a closed subspace of $L^1([0,1])$.